# Expressing SQL nested conditions in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this SQL fragment:

```
and (
     (notrequired is not null and notrequired <= datedue)
     or 
     (datefulfilled is not null and datefulfilled <= datedue)
)
```

I have tried expressing it like this:

```
""or"": [
    {{
        ""and"": [
            {{
                ""exists"": {{ ""field"": ""NotRequired"" }}
            }},
            {{
                ""script"": {{
                    ""script"": ""doc['NotRequired'].value <= doc['DateDue'].value""
                }}
            }}
        ],
        ""and"": [
            {{
                ""exists"": {{ ""field"": ""DateFulfilled"" }}
            }},
            {{
                ""script"": {{
                    ""script"": ""doc['DateFulfilled'].value <= doc['DateDue'].value""
                }}
            }}
        ]
    }}
]
```

The outer most `and` is done as a filter on an aggregate that has a filter applied to it. So there is a

```
aggs: { 
    "name": { 
        filter: {}, 
        aggs: { 
            "inner" : { 
                filter: {} 
             } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

the inner filter is where everything inside the `and` sql fragment is applied. So by my reckoning because you're filtering inside a filter then the `and` is applied.

Excuse the escaping of the ES fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I had formatted the search wrong:

```
""or"": [
    {{
        ""and"": [
            {{
                ""exists"": {{ ""field"": ""NotRequired"" }}
            }},
            {{
                ""script"": {{
                    ""script"": ""doc['NotRequired'].value <= doc['DateDue'].value""
                }}
            }}
        ]
    }}, 
    {{
        ""and"": [
            {{
                ""exists"": {{ ""field"": ""DateFulfilled"" }}
            }},
            {{
                ""script"": {{
                    ""script"": ""doc['DateFulfilled'].value <= doc['DateDue'].value""
                }}
            }}
        ]
    }}
]
```

Each `and` needed to be inside it's own object!